# Values between pages with Apex

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried looking for an answer, but everything I found seemed too high level. I am a college student who's working on a database project. We need to use apex (oracle) to shred data from an open API source. You can see what me & my team are working on here: http://bit.ly/Jvt4av.

I have listing of movies with links. Those links go to another page that is supposed to show all sorts of details for that movie.

I have successfully passed the movie_id variable between the list and the detail page, but I am stumped now. I need to show the movie's details and I don't want to use reports or forms because they're too ugly to show this kind of info. I want to be able to show the data with HTML. So, my questions are:

- Where/how do I query the database, so I can use the results in HTML?
- How do I display those results in HTML?

Thank you!

Comment: if you want to just use raw html, APEX probably isn't the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have the movie ID then you can use it to query the database and get all the other details from the database. If you want to render those details using just plain HTML then a PL/SQL region in conjunction with some htp.p calls will do the job. For example:

```
for x in (select * from movies_details where id=<MOVIE_ID>) loop
  htp.p('<h1>' || x.movie_title || '</h1>');
end loop
```